# Create new page with navigation different in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

At home page, the block main menu is "Home", "OMS" , "AMS", "PMS", "Set list" and the The Navigation is similar the main menu. when i click OMS, i want the Navigation is OMS setting, Add OMS, Edit and so on for "AMS", "PMS". Please look the picture below

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to overload the css files...you can do that by creating a new theme..
you can go to http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-theme and see how to make a simple theme...
For example to you custom design the navigation system, you would style it with css by accessing the dev that containt the block which identified by the id 
        #block-system-navigation
and so on...

Comment: can you explain more detail. Thanks :)